# android interface, Fragment replace error

Tags: java, android

I'm sending an interface from Fragment 5 to 3 through the main activity :

```
   public void setF3Riddle(int x) {

        Frag3 F3 = (Frag3)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Frag3);

        if (F3 != null) {
            F3.getF3Riddle(x);
        } else {
            Frag3 frag = new Frag3();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("Value", x);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.Frag3, frag)
                   .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            frag.getF3Riddle(x);
    }
}
```

But it crashes when i send the data while running. I've noticed the problem when i change the `.replace(R.id.Frag3,Frag)` container to another fragment it doesnt crash what's the problem here?

note: when i put other layouts it works except Frag 3, 2 ,1

Fragment 3 Layout:

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Frag3"
tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.Frag3">
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are telling it crashes but I cant see any stack trace in your post.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Mike M sorry that was a mistake i was going to every website and asking this question to get the answer sooner and i asked it twice here